# Integer array to binary array

Tags: arrays, matlab, binary

I have an integer array:

```
a=[3,4,5,6,7];
```

I want to convert it to a binary array with four bits each. For the above integer array I would like get the following binary array:

```
abinary=[0,0,1,1, 0,1,0,0, 0,1,0,1, 0,1,1,0, 0,1,1,1];
```

Is there any fast way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decimal to binary as double type array, not string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274368/decimal-to-binary-as-double-type-array-not-string)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Matlab has the built-in function [DEC2BIN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/dec2bin.html). It creates a character array, but it's easy to turn that back to numbers.

```
%# create binary string - the 4 forces at least 4 bits
bstr = dec2bin([3,4,5,6,7],4)

%# convert back to numbers (reshape so that zeros are preserved)
out = str2num(reshape(bstr',[],1))'
```

Comment: Do you have something similar to python?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [BITGET](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/bitget.html) function:

```
abinary = [bitget(a,4); ...  %# Get bit 4 for each number
           bitget(a,3); ...  %# Get bit 3 for each number
           bitget(a,2); ...  %# Get bit 2 for each number
           bitget(a,1)];     %# Get bit 1 for each number
abinary = abinary(:)';      %'# Make it a 1-by-20 array
```

Comment: I didn't even know about bitget. I'd make a loop to construct abinary, though, in order to be able to use this for any number of bits. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A late answer I know, but MATLAB has a function to do this directly `de2bi`

```
out = de2bi([3,4,5,6,7], 4, 'left-msb');
```

Comment: `de2bi` is only available in the [Communications System Toolbox](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/de2bi.html). A similar function `decimalToBinaryVector` exists in the [Data Acquisition Toolbox](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/daq/ref/decimaltobinaryvector.html).