# Decimal to binary as double type array, not string

Tags: matlab, binary, octave

I have this so far:

```
data = 14
out = dec2bin(data, 4)
```

which gives:

```
out = 1110
```

But I want to get binary number in this format:

```
out = [1 1 1 0]
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [**`de2bi`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/de2bi.html) with the `'left-msb'` option.

```
data = 14
out = de2bi(data, 4,'left-msb')
```

Which requires the **Communication Systems Toolbox** though. Alternatively use your original approach with the fundamental [**`dec2bin`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html) with the following addition:

```
data = 14
out = double( dec2bin(data, 4) ) - 48
```

---

```
out =

     1     1     1     0
```

Comment: Yes but this require to use communications package and I can't use it

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [**`de2bi`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/de2bi.html),
[**`bi2de`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/bi2de.html)
functions.

It requires the **Communication Systems Toolbox**.

If you don't have it, you can work define these functions at the begining of your code as:

```
de2bi = @(x) dec2bin(x)>48;
bi2de = @(x) x*2.^(size(x,2)-1:-1:0)';
```

Test:

```
dec = 1:10
bin = de2bi(dec)
dec = bi2de(bin)
```

Output:

```
dec =

    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10

bin =

  0  0  0  1
  0  0  1  0
  0  0  1  1
  0  1  0  0
  0  1  0  1
  0  1  1  0
  0  1  1  1
  1  0  0  0
  1  0  0  1
  1  0  1  0

dec =

    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
   10
```

**P.S.** If, by some reason, you don't want to use **`dec2bin`**  at all, you can define **`de2bi`** function as:

In **Matlab/Octave**:

```
de2bi = @(x)  2.^[(floor(log2(max(x(:)))):-1:1),0];
de2bi = @(x) rem(x(:),2*de2bi(x))>(de2bi(x)-1);
```

In **Octave** only (as far as Octave allows default values for anonymous functions):

By default returns the same as in the previous example, but optional bit position parameter is available:

```
de2bi = @(dec,bit=[(1+floor(log2(max(dec(:))))):-1:2, 1]) rem(dec(:),2.^bit)>(2.^(bit-1)-1);

%Call examples:
x=0:10; 
n=3:-1:1;
de2bi(x)
de2bi(x,n)   % returns only the three least significant bits
```

**P.S.** More common answer provided here: [`dec2base with independent bits/digits calculation`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67077847/6165594)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way: Use "bitget":

```
data = 14
out = bitget (data, 4:-1:1)
out =
   1   1   1   0
```