# Have to convert Integer to binary

Tags: matlab

I'm writing a user-defined function to convert integers to binary. The largest number that could be converted with the function should be a binary number with
16 1 s. If a larger number is entered as d, the function should display an error
message. With my code, I'm trying to add the numbers 0 or 1 to my vector x based on the remainder, then I want to reverse my final vector to display a number in binary. Here's what I have:

```
function [b] = bina(d)
% Bina is a function that converts integers to binary

x  = [];
y  = 2;
in = d/2;

if d >=(2^16 -1)
   fprintf('This number is too big')
else
    while in > 1
        if in >= 1
            r = rem(in,y);
            x = [x r]
        end
    end
end

end
```

Comment: how about using `de2bi`: http://mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/de2bi.html

Comment: @m.s. That requires communications toolbox that many might not have.

Comment: Could you post sample input and expected output, please.

Comment: is this homework? Otherwise look at `dec2bin` in octave.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve with the above code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decimal to binary as double type array, not string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274368/decimal-to-binary-as-double-type-array-not-string)

Comment: [**`bin = double( dec2bin(integer, 4) ) - 48`**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29275198/2605073)

Comment: you are not updating the variable `in` in the while loop, that will be an infinite loop.

Comment: I'm supposed to convert the 4 numbers: 100, 1002, 52601, and 200090. Every time I run it, I get an infinite loop. How do I update the in variable in the while loop to fix the code?

Comment: Or how can I change my code to successfully convert those numbers to binary without using the dec2bin command?

Comment: @NotAMathMan Please consider accepting the answer, to indicate the system that your problem is solved. (green check mark on the left) thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you insist on a loop:

```
x = [];
y = 2;
in = d;


if d >=(2^16 -1)
   fprintf('This number is too big')
else
   ii = 1;
   while in > 0
        r = logical(rem(in,y^ii));
        x = [r x];
        in = in - r*2^(ii-1);
        ii = ii+1;
   end
end

b = x;
```

You had the right ideas, but you need to update the variables in your while-loop with every iteration. This is mainly `in`, where you need to subtract the remainder. And just store the binary remainders in your variable `x`.

You can check your result with

```
x = double( dec2bin(d, 16) ) - 48
```

You could also use a for loop, by pre-calculating the number of iterations with

```
find( d < 2.^(1:16),1)
```

and then

```
if d >=(2^16 -1)
   fprintf('This number is too big')
else
   for ii = 1:find( d < 2.^(1:16),1)
        r = logical(rem(in,y^ii));
        x = [r x];
        in = in - r*2^(ii-1)
   end
end
```