# Binary array usage with bin2dec octave

Tags: octave

I have an array like [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ] that i would like to convert to a number using bin2dec, is there a way to do it like with dec2bin, where you just use -'0' or would I have to go trough string operations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decimal to binary as double type array, not string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274368/decimal-to-binary-as-double-type-array-not-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to dig it out, for anyone looking this can be done using bin2dec(num2str(binary))