# dec2base with independent bits/digits calculation

Tags: algorithm, matlab, octave, numeric, radix

Need **`MATLAB`**/**`Octave`** **`dec2base`** functionality function with independent bits/digits calculation algorithm (within **integer** logic, with no divisions, using modular arithmetic).

Would be nice to have as well:

1. anonymous function

---

**NB!**
floating logic and division could be used only one time for scalar to define the maximal amount of digits in converted numbers array:

```
ceil( log2(max(dec(:)))/log2(base)) )
```

**The best answers:**

1. [Anonymous function solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67077847/6165594)
2. [Regular Function solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68407679/6165594)

**P.S.**

1. Solution for simplified **`dec2bin`** case listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57856041/6165594).
2. Solution for **`bitget`** provided in this post: [Matlab/Octave bitget function for any base](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67127079/6165594)

Comment: How can “must be anonymous function” ever be a meaningful requirement?

Comment: @CrisLuengo, thank you for the remark.
Question updated, impicit "must" replaced by explicit "nice to have"

Comment: @CrisLuengo, regarding "meaningful requirement":
1) In some scenarious anonymous functions work faster (in my tests for the small (around 100) input arrays for instance).
2) If you have anonymous function, not a big deal to write the regular function. Can't say the same for vice versa scenario.
3) I just sympathize to compact solutions (very personal).
;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In **`MATLAB`** / **`OCTAVE`**:

   ```
   % For Matlab/Octave: 
   de2bs = @(dec,base) base.^([(1+floor( log2(max(dec(:)))/log2(base)) ):-1:1]-1); % an array of powers of a base
   de2bs = @(dec,base) sum(rem(dec(:)                                ...
                              ,base.*de2bs(dec,base)                 ...
                              )                                      ...
                           >=permute((1:base-1)'*(de2bs(dec,base))   ...
                                    ,[3,2,1]                         ...
                                    )                                ...
                           ,3                                        ...
                           );
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   x=0:9; base=3; de2bs(x,base)

   ans =

   0   0   0
   0   0   1
   0   0   2
   0   1   0
   0   1   1
   0   1   2           
   0   2   0
   0   2   1
   0   2   2
   1   0   0
   ```
2. In **`OCTAVE`** only: as far as Octave supports default values for anonymous
   functions, there is a more interesting overloaded function
   implementation:

   ```
   % OCTAVE only (Matlab do not support default values for parameters)

   % Anonymous function de2bs
   % dig = digget(dec, base, isoutputasstring, pos)                
   %   dig  - returns the value of the digits in positions (pos) for numbers (dec)
   %          coverted to the defined base (for base=2 behaves similar to bitget) 
   %   dec  - mandatory, initial decimal numbers vector
   %   base - optional (by default base = 2),
   %          base to convert (for binary base = 2 )
   %   isoutputasstring - optional (by default isoutputasstring = true), 
   %          example: de2bs(26,16,0) -> '1A'
   %          example: de2bs(26,16,1) -> [1 10]%   
   %   pos  - optional (by default pos = (ceil( log2(max(dec(:)))/log2(base)) ):-1:1 ) 
   %          array of positions (like in bitget function)

   de2bs = @(dec
           ,base = [2]                                                  ... % Base of numbers you want to get
           ,isoutputinstringformat = [true]                             ... % output format 0/1 - integer/string 
           ,pos  = [(ceil( log2(max(dec(:)))/log2(base)) ):-1:1]        ... % Bits/digits positions to return (similar to bitget function)
       ... % temporary variables listed below (NOT parameters)          ...
           ,pbs  = [base.^(pos-1)]                                      ... % pbs - powers of base
           ,num  = [sum(rem(dec(:)                                      ... % conversion to defined base
                           ,base.*pbs                                   ...
                           )                                            ...
                       >= permute((1:base-1)'*pbs                       ...
                                 ,[3,2,1]                               ...
                                 )                                      ...
                       ,3                                               ...
                       )                                                ...
                   ]                                                    ...
           )                                                            ...
           ifelse(isoutputinstringformat                                ... % Convert digits to chars if necessary
                 ,char(ifelse(num>9,num+55, num+48))                    ... % like 9->'9', 10->'A', 11->'B';
                 ,num                                                   ... 
                 );
   ```

   Examples:

   ```
   x=25:28;
   base=16;


   de2bs(x)        % behaves as dec2bin(x)

   ans =

   11001
   11010
   11011
   11100        


   de2bs(x,base)   % behaves as dec2base(x,base)

   ans =

   19
   1A
   1B
   1C


   de2bs(x,base,0) % behaves as dec2base(x,base) without converting/mapping to string/char format

   ans =

   1    9
   1   10
   1   11
   1   12


   de2bs(x,base,1,[3 2 1])   % behaves as dec2base(x,base), but returns mentioned digits in number (like in bitget function)

   ans =

   019
   01A
   01B
   01C
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it as regular function (requires **MatLab** version with [Compatible Array Sizes for Basic Operations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compatible-array-sizes-for-basic-operations.html) support):

```
function dig = de2bs(dec, base, isoutputnumerical, pos) 
% de2bs(D)
% de2bs(D, BASE)
% de2bs(D, BASE, ISOUTPUTNUMERICAL)  
% de2bs(D, BASE, ISOUTPUTNUMERICAL, POS)
%
% de2bs(D)
%     Return a binary number corresponding to the non-negative integer D
%     (Behaves the same as dec2bin(D) )
%     
%         de2bs([123,321])  
%         ans = 001111011
%               101000001
%
% de2bs(D, BASE)
%     Return a string of symbols in base BASE corresponding 
%     to the non-negative integer D.
%     
%         de2bs(123, 3)  
%         ans = 011120
%               102220
%  
%     If BASE is a string then the base is calculated as length(BASE),
%     and characters of BASE are used as the symbols for the digits of D.  
%
%          de2bs (123, "aBc")
%          ans = aBBBca
%                Baccca
% 
% de2bs(D, BASE, ISOUTPUTNUMERICAL)  
%     By default, ISOUTPUTNUMERICAL is false   
%
%          de2bs([123,321],16,0) 
%          ans = 07B
%                141
%
%          de2bs([123,321],16,1) 
%          ans = 0    7   11
%                1    4    1
%
%
% de2bs(D, BASE, ISOUTPUTNUMERICAL, POS)
%     POS  - optional array of digits positions (like in bitget function)
%            By default pos = (ceil( log2(max(dec(:)))/log2(base)) ):-1:1 ) 
%
%          dde2bs([123,321],3,0)          
%          ans = 011120
%                102220
%           
%          de2bs([123,321],3,0,8:-2:2)
%          ans = 0012
%                0122
%
% See also: dec2base, base2dec, dec2bin, dec2hex.


% parsing input parameters ------------------------------------------
if nargin < 2  base = 2; end

symbols = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

if (ischar(base))  symbols = base;  base = length(symbols); end
if  nargin < 3  isoutputnumerical = false; end

max_len = ceil( log2(max(dec(:)))/log2(base));

if  nargin < 4  pos = [max_len:-1:1]; end


% Conver decimals into base -----------------------------------------
pbs = [base.^(pos-1)];        % pbs - powers of base
dig = sum(rem(dec(:), base.*pbs) >= permute((1:base-1)'*pbs,[3,2,1]),3);    % TODO - with for loop requires less calculations (this is just example with compact code)

if isoutputnumerical == false  dig = reshape(symbols(dig+1), size(dig)); end
```