# Matlab/Octave bitget function for any base

Tags: matlab, binary, octave, numeric, radix

Need function like **`bitget`**, but for any base.

Would be nice to have as well:

1. array input and array bit selection
2. anonymous function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Implementaion for **`Matlab`** (for **`Octave`** will work as well, but I recommend the 2nd option):

   ```
   % Anonymous function digget
   % dig = digget(dec, base, pos)                
   %   dig  - returns the value of the digits in positions (pos) for numbers (dec)
   %          coverted to the defined base (for base=2 behaves similar to bitget) 
   %   dec  - initial decimal numbers vector
   %   base - base to convert (for binary base = 2 )
   %   pos  - array of positions 
   %          if pos = [(ceil( log2(max(dec(:)))/log2(base)) ):-1:1] 
   %          behaves similar as dec2base function
   %
   % Examples:
   % dig = digget(1:8, 2, 2:-1:1)
   %
   % dig =
   %
   %   0   1
   %   1   0
   %   1   1
   %   0   0
   %   0   1
   %   1   0
   %   1   1
   %   0   0
   % 
   %
   % dig = digget(8:15, 13, 3:-1:1)
   %
   % dig =
   %
   %    0    0    8
   %    0    0    9
   %    0    0   10
   %    0    0   11
   %    0    0   12
   %    0    1    0
   %    0    1    1
   %    0    1    2

   digget = @(dec,base,pbit) sum(rem(dec(:),base.*pbit)>= permute((1:base-1)'*pbit,[3,2,1]),3);
   digget = @(dec,base, bit) digget(dec,base,base.^(bit-1));
   ```
2. Implementaion for **`Octave`**:
   as far as Octave supports default values for inline function, it completely covered by  [de2bs
   function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67077847/6165594) (see 2nd option)